# Group Homomorphisms into an Abelian Group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

The following comes from Hungerford's *Algebra.*

> [Prove that if] $f: G \to H$ is a homomorphism, $H$ is abelian and $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $\ker f$, then $N$ is normal in $G.$

A solution found [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/mashker/files/2010/02/sol-manual-hungeford.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj64e7KvP7gAhUkgK0KHfvHBHEQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw0yJIavwJvM6Rpv_i3lSBOe) (at I.5.16) begins by saying "since $H$ is abelian, $f(H)$ is an abelian subgroup." Obviously, this makes sense, but the domain of $f$ is $G.$  Why does $f(H)$ make sense here? This is really the part of the proof I don't understand.

Is there also another way to proceed with the proof?

Comment: It seems to be a typo.  Try reading it as "$f(G)$ is an abelian subgroup" instead.

Comment: Look at Theorem 5.11 on page 45 of Hungerford.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subgroups containing kernel of group morphism to an abelian group are normal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542264/subgroups-containing-kernel-of-group-morphism-to-an-abelian-group-are-normal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entire solution is wrong, in my opinion. For instance following sentence in the proof don’t make any sense: Thus for every $g\in G$, $n\in N$, $(gH)nH(g^{-1}H)=(gH)(g^{-1}H)nH=nH$. Product between elements of $G$ and $H$ are not defined. There are two approaches to solve this exercise. One of the solution is bit harder relative to another. [First](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/260066/861687) (easy) approach and [second](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/260064/861687) approach.